# CakePHP: Associated models using a single database table

Tags: cakephp, model

Using CakePHP:

In my example I have a model named `users` and then associated models `admins`, `students`, `parents`.

Now, each `admin`, `student` and `user` `belongsTo` a `user`. (In addition each `student` `belongsTo` a `parent`)

I need separate controllers for each of the models but I don't want to have a separate database table for each model. i.e. All the `users` are stored in the `users` table and have a `user_type` of admin, parent or child.

Firstly, is this the correct way of setting it up, or should each `student`, `admin` etc. model have it's own table in the database? And secondly, how do I make models that are based on the tables of their associated models?

Comment: Why do you "need separate controllers"?

Comment: @Dave I guess I don't need separate controllers? But do I need separate models?

Answer (score 0):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable

```
class Example extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = false; // This model does not use a database table
}
```

Cake allow you to have model that not connected to any database table.

Use models without any db table or not is your choice I think :)